# Use DISTINCT to display unique items

Tags: sql, postgresql, duplicates, postgresql-13

I have 2 tables which I would like to query and display data differences:

```
CREATE TABLE order_splits_config (
    id                   INT,
    pair_id              INT
);

CREATE TABLE active_pairs (
    id                  INT,
    pair                VARCHAR(30),
    exchange_active     boolean,
    exchange_id         INT
);

INSERT INTO order_splits_config(id, pair_id)
VALUES (1, 83);
INSERT INTO order_splits_config(id, pair_id)
VALUES (2, 58);
INSERT INTO order_splits_config(id, pair_id)
VALUES (34, 34);

INSERT INTO active_pairs(id, pair, exchange_active, exchange_id)
VALUES (1, 'US/EN', true, 2);
INSERT INTO active_pairs(id, pair, exchange_active, exchange_id)
VALUES (2, 'GB/UK', true, 3);
INSERT INTO active_pairs(id, pair, exchange_active, exchange_id)
VALUES (2, 'FR/EU', true, 4);
```

I use this query to query the differences:

```
SELECT b.id, b.pair, b.exchange_id
FROM order_splits_config a
FULL OUTER JOIN active_pairs b
ON a.pair_id = b.id
WHERE a.pair_id IS NULL
OR b.id IS NULL
AND b.exchange_active = 'true';
```

This prints a lot of lines like this for example (data is just for example):

```
#,pair,id,exchange_id
1, US/EN,332,1
2, GB/UK,112,1
3, GB/UK,113,1
4, FR/EU,221,5
5, FR/EU,183,2
...
```

How can I use `DISTINCT` in order to get the result from the query unique by `pair`?

FIDDLE: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/4D6VfqysPCWhQnh8zaFBps/2

Comment: It's nice that you provided table definitions, sample data, and a query. It would be great if they were reproducible (i.e. free from obvious errors).

Comment: Sure, here it is: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/4D6VfqysPCWhQnh8zaFBps/2

Comment: Always group conditions by parentheses in case of `OR` predicate to: 1) clearly define what you want to `AND`. 2) do not rely on default evaluation order and avoid unexpected results. When you use some column of the outer joined table in the where clause (except `is null` predicate), you turn outer join to inner.

Comment: Thank you for the advice. Can you give me a hand how to resolve the problem, please?

Comment: To be honest I selected it randomly. I don't think that version is very important for the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You only select columns from table `active_pairs` to begin with.

After joining on `a.pair_id = b.id`, the condition `a.pair_id IS NULL` is only true if there is no matching row in table `order_splits_config AS a`, which is more efficiently formulated as `NOT EXISTS` instead of the `FULL JOIN`.

As for `b.id IS NULL AND b.exchange_active = 'true'`: again, `b.id` can only be `NULL` for rows of `a` where no matching `b` is found - in which case `b.exchange_active` can never be true. So the clause effectively eliminates all rows of `a` that were just added by the `FULL JOIN` and which would show up in the result as all NULL values since there are only columns from `b`. In short: don't `FULL JOIN` to begin with.

If `active_pairs.pair` is defined `UNIQUE`, it boils down to:

```sql
SELECT id, pair, exchange_id
FROM   active_pairs b
WHERE  NOT EXISTS (SELECT FROM order_splits_config a WHERE a.pair_id = b.id);
```

If `active_pairs.pair` is not defined `UNIQUE`, the simple solution is with `DISTINCT ON`:

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT ON (pair)
       id, pair, exchange_id
FROM   active_pairs b
WHERE  NOT EXISTS (SELECT FROM order_splits_config a WHERE a.pair_id = b.id);
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=011b2b1af76ca937363ffa2920a75346)*

From each set of duplicates on `pair`, you get an **arbitrary** pick.
For a **deterministic** pick, define what to pick and add an `ORDER BY` clause accordingly. Example: to get the one with the smallest `id`, add:

```
...
ORDER BY pair, id;
```

Also adds a sort order to the so far unsorted result.

If `order_splits_config` isn't trivially small, have an index on `(pair_id)` to make this fast.

There may be ***much*** faster solutions for a big `active_pairs` table, depending on undisclosed information, mostly the cardinality of column `pair` (how many duplicate values).

See:

- [Select first row in each GROUP BY group?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3800551/select-first-row-in-each-group-by-group/7630564#7630564)
- [Select rows which are not present in other table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19363481/select-rows-which-are-not-present-in-other-table/19364694#19364694)
- [Optimize GROUP BY query to retrieve latest row per user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25536422/optimize-group-by-query-to-retrieve-latest-row-per-user/25536748#25536748)

Comment: Thanks, `pair_id` can have multiple records with value 'FR/EU'. `pair VARCHAR(30),` is not unique.

Comment: For just a few duplicates, `DISTINCT ON` is typically fastest. (It's simplest anyway.) See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34715134/939860